# Doing an assignment within python next()

Tags: python, iterator

Is it possible to do an assignment within `next()` function. For an example, consider following line. It searches a `text` for a given list of `patterns` and returns `True` if a match is found.

```
foundPattern = next((True for pattern in patterns  if pattern in text), False)
```

Is it possible to assign the `pattern` which get matched to be used outside `next()` function.

Comment: You probably don't want to use a generator comprehension then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a tuple

```
retval, foundPattern = next(((True, pattern) for pattern in patterns  if pattern in text), (False, None))
```

Comment: I imagined that he needs the True/False check he started with. Although "text" should stand for "text", in a generic case "text" could be another type of object supporting "in" and "pattern" could be "None". Returning the tuple avoids that case.

Comment: @mementum: The information about whether a match was found is already represented by whether `foundPattern` is `None`.

Comment: It is not in the generic case as explained in my previous comment. If "text" happens to be a dictionary and one of the "patterns" happens to be "None" and "None" is a key in "text", there will be a match.

Comment: yes of coarse there are cases where my strategy falls down... I just was assuming we could take OP at face value and assume that your edge case that fails is not a valid case for OP ... (I am not sure if this is the case, however barring evidence to the contrary I am sticking with this assumptions)

Comment: @mementum: That can still be fixed even if `None` might be returned on success. The trick is to create a guaranteed unique sentinel value: `sentinel = object()`, `foundPattern = next((pattern for pattern in patterns  if pattern in text), sentinel)`, then `foundPattern` is either the matching pattern or the `sentinel`, testing `if foundPattern is not sentinel:` (or `is sentinel`, as appropriate) efficiently checks whether you got a hit. The sentinel can be initialized as a keyword (kwonly on Py3 for safety) argument if desired, which avoids creating a new one on each call to the function.